# Simulation software recommendations

Tags: thermodynamics, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, software, heat-conduction

I need a preferably free (open source or student edition) software for modelling of heat diffusion on a cylindrical geometry for a project. What would you recommend?

Comment: You could try [OpenFOAM](https://www.openfoam.com/) and look at [diffusion< ReactionThermo, ThermoType > Class Template Reference](https://www.openfoam.com/documentation/guides/latest/api/classFoam_1_1combustionModels_1_1diffusion.html)

Comment: @BrendanDarrer Please don't answer questions using comments. To answer a closed question, first vote to reopen.

Comment: While recommendations are listed in the [types of questions we don't answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/computational-physics/info) w.r.t. the comp-physics tag, it might be prudent for you to consider more details about your model. For instance, are you looking for 2D? 3D? Is it just a cylinder that is radiating heat, or are there boundary sources? Are there additional parameters, such as a GUI, language, etc that might narrow it down?

Comment: That said, and I have 0 ideas about topicality, but there is [softwarerecs.se] that might be a suitable place for this type of question (but again, I don't know what is considered on or off topic there).